# All layers in ArcMap lined up, but when exported to CAD, they shifted to different locations

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcmap, cad

I have all the layers in ArcMap lined up correctly, but they shifted in CAD after I exported them. Why is it?

The data frame property shows current coordinate system:

Current coordinate system:

> NAD_1983_HARN_StatePlan_Oregon_North_FIPS_3601_Feet_Intl
>
> Projection: Lamber_Conformal_Conic. Geographic Coordinate System:
>
> GCS_North_American_1983_HARN Datum : D_North_American_1983_HARN

The layer of the drainage system feature class shows:

Coordinate System:

> NAD_1983_HARN_StatePlane_Oregon_North_FIPS_3601_Feet_Intl
>
> Projection : Lambert_Conformal_Conic
>
> Geographic Coordinate System : GCS_North_American_1983_HARN Datum : D_North_American_1983_HARN

The contour layer feature class has a Projected Coordinate System:

> NAD_1983_2011_Oregon_Statewide_Lambert_Feet_Intl
>
> Projection: Lambert_Conformal_Conic
>
> Geographic Coordinate System : GCS_NAD_1983_2011 Datum :
>   D_NAD_1983_2011

Comment: Did you try to transform all the layers to the same coordinate system before exporting them to CAD format?

Comment: Your CAD package, which you don't mention, doesn't appear to honor spatial reference properties. Just because GIS can perform "on the fly" reprojection doesn't mean it's wise to leave disparate data sources in different projections

Comment: Use geographic wgs84 for all datasets and then export to CAD